# Unable to access Figaro variables in engine.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, figaro-ruby

This is my engine.rb file. I am able to access Figaro variable in the middleware. But the `Stripe.api_key=Figaro.env.stripe_secret` is not working. Stripe api_key not set error is being shown .

```
  module Stripo

      require 'figaro'

      class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
        isolate_namespace Stripo
        Stripe.api_key=Figaro.env.stripe_secret
        middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
          provider :stripe_connect, Figaro.env.client_id,Figaro.env.stripe_secret,:scope => 'read_write'
        end

     end
  end
```

How can I set Stripe api_key from Figaro variable in my engine?

Comment: `Stripe.api_key= ENV['stripe_secret']` should work fine, provided that the key for your stripe secret number is saved inside your `application.yml` as `stripe_secret`.

Comment: It doesnt work. I am working on an engine. And the above code is written inside engine.rb

Comment: What about `ENV.fetch('stripe_secret')`?

Comment: Can you show an example of your `application.yml`?

Comment: This didnt work . So I added an initializers folder and set api key there.

Comment: ` publishable_key: "pk_tebEEAxS0Wb2Sd8IB1LpAjs"
client_id: "ca_7CmEzS4NfEz4PNkiwAUhvBA9gQ"
stripe_secret: "sk_test_o9YlLXk88DfsdQtPEqZ" `

this is my application.yml

Comment: DId you ever solve this? @raj